# How can i get a sticky footer 40px margin-below and above

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to make my footer stick to the bottom of the page. I want it to have 40px margin above and below but its not working out and keeps going over content in my site. Can someone help me out?

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-line"> </div>
  <div id="footer-nav"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="expertise.html">Expertise</a> | <a href="doctors.html">Doctors</a> | <a href="facility.html">Facility</a> | <a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></div>
  <div id="footer-copyright">© 2013 Website, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</div>
</div>

#footer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0;

}
#footer-line {
    margin: auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #C9DA2A;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
#footer-nav {
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer-nav a {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer-copyright {
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    height: 33px;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-top: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 margins defined in `#footer`:

```
#footer {
margin: auto; <----
width: 900px;
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 40px; <----
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0;

}
```

It should be `margin: 40px auto;` As a fixed element, it's going to go over the content on your site. You need to accomodate that by shrinking your content container to the height of the fixed bar.

Answer (score 0):

Put a div at the bottom of your content.  Something like...

`<div class="push"></div>`

Then style it with something like this...

```
.push {
height: 30px;
clear: both;
```

}

Should get everything pushed down.  Works fine on every site I've used it on.

Answer (score 0):

check out the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HZ5NW/

add another div around your code as shown in the fiddle, remove these two lines of css from the footer and add them to the container div.

```
#container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

Comment: But if i make the window smaller height wise it goes over my content?

Comment: that is because its fixed. did you not want to see any content that goes behind? like this maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/HZ5NW/1/